# ruby on rails usage of debugger and ytml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm new to ruby on rails.

Can anyone suggest a debugging method for ruby on rails.
(Like `var_dump`, `print_r` in php).

I saw `debugger` and `ytml`. could anyone explain how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your Gemfile

```
gem 'debugger'
```

then bundle install.

Then use like this in methods

```
def index
  debugger       
  @files = Example.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

And in views(.erb) use like this.

```
<%debugger%>
```

This will cause debugger to break code execution and give you an interactive console on the line "debugger". You can type "step" to dive into the line of code or type "next" to stay at the same level and process the line you're on.

Typing "continue or c" will resume code execution until the next "debugger" line is encountered, if any

Comment: thanx,.. but.. while executing bundle install i'm facing "Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Comment: The debugger gem isn't supposed to be used with ruby 2.0+, and literally won't install with ruby 2.1.2. You are going to have to switch to byebug.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look into [pry](http://pryrepl.org/), a debugging REPL you can use inside of rails. For other cases, there's the `rails console` command, which will allow you to open up a REPL in the context of your running application in development mode, and should be sufficient for most development needs.